# Como abro um link ao clicar em uma div

Tags: html, css

ao clicar na div, preciso que acesse um link na internet, como faço isso?

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 50px;
}

.box{
    background-color: rgb(58, 58, 104);
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 40px;

    transition-property: border-radius;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.box:hover{
    border-radius: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.frete{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.box img{
    border-radius: 50px;
    
}

.box p{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
        <h1>Bicicleta</h1>
        <div class="frete">
            <p>frete gratis</p>
        </div>
        <img src="img/bike.webp" width="380px" height="400px">
        <p>Apenas R$499,99!</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Coloque a imagem como um link, assim:

```
<a href="endereço da imagem na internet">
    <img src="img/bike.webp" width="380px" height="400px">
</a>
```